# Accessing an embedded RavenDB instance from another process

Tags: ravendb

We're considering to host RavenDB in embedded mode inside our (load-balanced) front-end servers for caching purposes. However, we also have a Windows Service that needs to occasionally connect to the RavenDB database to insert document and query the indexes. If we enable the embedded HTTP server of RavenDB, would it be possible to connect to that same instance from the Windows Service?

Comment: you said using caching in an Embedded Server mode - how will you keep them in sync? Would it be better to go direct to the source?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. You can expose the embedded server over HTTP.
Note that usually you are better of at that point with just a standard RavenDB Server.